# Binding a named-volume to a file in the container not working, only works for a directory

Tags: docker

In my docker-compose I have a named-volume like this `config:/var/lib/myservice/config.yml`. When I start the container I expect the config.yml file to be at: `var/lib/docker/volume/myservice_config/_data` on the host machine, but the _data folder is empty.

But if i write the named-volume without the filename like this: `config:/var/lib/myservice` then the `config.yml` appears in the `_data` folder

So does named-volume only work when pointing at a directory and not at a absolute path to a file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A named volume *is* a directory, and you can't bind a directory to a file -- it doesn't make sense. That's the same thing as if you tried something like this:

```
docker run -v /path/to/a/directory:/var/lib/myservice/config.yml
```

Even if `config.yml` was a file in the underlying image, you've just mounted a directory on top of it.

Comment: Is it possible to mount single file via named volume?

Comment: It is not possible to mount a single file from a named volume.